# What's the "if (Control == null)" section used for in a Xamarin iOS renderer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Looking at an example snippet from Xamarin, I saw that they suggest creating a custom renderer with three sections:

1. if (Control == null)
2. if (e.OldElement != null)
3. if (e.NewElement != null)

My renderer looks like this. However, I do not understand what I would use the `if (Control == null)` section for.

**Question 1)** Can anyone give me advice on how this would be used, and also if there's anything wrong with my implementation?

**Question 2)** Am I implementing this correctly, and how/where should I remove the `OnTabbarControllerItemSelected` handler?

**Question 3)** Where does the Control element come from? Would that be the same variable that I have called `_page` or the element `e`?

```
tabbarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;

public class TabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
{
    private MainPage _page;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        //if (Control == null)
        //{
        //    // Instantiate the native control
        //}

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
            e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= Current_PropertyChanged;
            return;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            // Configure the control and subscribe to event handlers
            TabBar.Translucent = false;
            TabBar.BackgroundImage = new UIImage();
            _page = (MainPage)e.NewElement;
            e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += Current_PropertyChanged;
        }

        try
        {
            var tabbarController = (UITabBarController)this.ViewController;
            if (tabbarController != null)
            {
                tabbarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;
                UpdateTheme();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }

    private void OnTabbarControllerItemSelected(object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (!(_page.CurrentPage is Japanese.CardsTabPage) && App.quizRunning == true)
            _page.CurrentPage = App.navCardsTabPage;
    }

    void Current_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Theme")
            UpdateTheme();
    }

    void UpdateTheme()
    {
        switch (_page.Theme)
        {
            default:
            case TH.Light:
                TabBar.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.Red;
                break;
            case TH.Dark: 
                TabBar.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.Red;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1 & 3

The snippet is for writing custom renderers, the `Control` property is in [ViewRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/ViewRenderer.cs#L50) class. Since your control inherits from `TabbedRenderer`, it's not necessary to follow the snippet.

> Question 2

[ViewController](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/7cc9a282bdeb76405c793574ebe0d096072f4228/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/TabbedRenderer.cs#L88) property returns the `TabbedRenderer` itself, so you don't need to add the listener every time `OnElementChanged` invoked. Consider move it to the constructor.

Like this:

```csharp
public class TabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
{
    private MainPage _page;

    public TabbedPageRenderer()
    {
        this.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
            e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= Current_PropertyChanged;
            return;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            // Configure the control and subscribe to event handlers
            TabBar.Translucent = false;
            TabBar.BackgroundImage = new UIImage();
            _page = (MainPage)e.NewElement;
            e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += Current_PropertyChanged;
        }

        if(_page != null)
            UpdateTheme();
    }

    private void OnTabbarControllerItemSelected(object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (_page != null && !(_page.CurrentPage is Japanese.CardsTabPage) && App.quizRunning == true)
            _page.CurrentPage = App.navCardsTabPage;
    }

    void Current_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Theme")
            UpdateTheme();
    }

    void UpdateTheme()
    {
        switch (_page.Theme)
        {
            default:
            case TH.Light:
                TabBar.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.Red;
                break;
            case TH.Dark: 
                TabBar.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.Red;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not the case that the current code continually adds with += the OnTabbarControllerItemSelected every time there is an OnElementChanged and never removes it?

Comment: Sorry I don't notice it, and I've updated my answer. You may also edit the code because there is another += line at the beginning.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you copy paste my code with your suggested corrections to the answer and then I will accept it.  Just a bit easier for people to follow if your suggestions appear in the answer.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted.  I will try it out and if it's all okay and no questions then I will accept.  Thanks again.

Comment: The code works good thanks.  But I am wondering, should I remove the OnTabbarControllerItemSelected in a protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)?

Comment: The event is inside the control (you can access it with `this`), so in fact it listens itself. When the control is destroyed, the listener is also destroyed.